# Automatically update child collection IDs after insert in bidirectional one-to-many association

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm sure this problem has been addressed before but I can't find a 'duplicate'. So the question is:

I have a bidirectional one-to-many association: **document** and **comments**.
The comments table has a foreign key (not nullable) pointing to documents table.
The classes are:

```
public class Document {
   public virtual Guid Id {get; set;}
   public virtual string Title {get; set;} 
   public virtual string Body {get; set;}
   public virtual IList<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}

public class Comment {
   public virtual Guid Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Document Document {get; set;}
   public virtual string Body {get; set;}
}

//Mappings

public class DocumentMap : ClassMap<Document> {
    public DocumentMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
       Map(x=>x.Title);
       Map(x=>x.Body);
       HasMany(x=>x.Comments).Inverse().Cascade.All().AsBag();
    }
}

public class CommentMap : ClassMap<Comment> {
    public CommentMap(){
       Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
       Map(x=>Body);
       References(x=>x.Document).Column("DocumentId").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

//The problem

var existingDocument = FetchDocumentFromDatabase(someDocumentGuidId);
Console.WriteLine(existingDocument.Comments.Count()); //0
existingDocument.Comments.Add(new Comment { Document = existingDocument, Body = "Test"});
session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(existingDocument);//all OK
//commiting transaction etc
Console.WriteLine(existingDocument.Comments[0].Id); 
// 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

But I need my new comment Id here!

The comment is added OK to DB but the object Id is still an empty Guid.

How do I automatically fill child object Ids after they were added as part of parent object update?

I'm using NHibernate 3.0.0 Alpha 3 (seems to be very stable) and Fluent NHibernate v.1.1.

Please advice.

UPDATE 1: all changes propage to DB just fine (document properties are updated as well as new comments are added).

Comment: I don't believe that you actually committed the transaction before the last write line.

Comment: This code is a simplified model, all db interactions are wrapped inside transactions.

Comment: hu? where are the transactions? they belong to the top most level of the business logic. You say that you commit the transaction before writeline, and the guid is still not set. I think, after committing, it should be there.

Comment: I can't provide all code here, this is just a tiny model, just trust me that I commit transaction. I'm interested in results, so there is no need to lie.

Comment: Can it be NHibernate 3.0.0 Alpha bug?

Comment: I don't say that you lie, I just want you to check your code. The Ids should actually be available after flushing the session. Try flushing it explicitly (within the transaction where you add the comments). It may also be a problem of SaveOrUpdateCopy, I've never used it.

Comment: Question still holds, I explicitly flush session and to no avail.

Comment: Are the new comments in the database? Are other changes on the document (eg on its title) stored?

Comment: guid.comb doesn't have anything to do with transactions. They are assigned as soon as the `Save` and associates are called. See my answer for more info.

Comment: I'm curious which of the options from my answer you eventually chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `SaveOrUpdateCopy`. What happens here is that `existingDocument` is not used to persist to the database.

From http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached:

> The last case can be avoided by using `SaveOrUpdateCopy(Object o)`. This method copies the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. The method returns the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, NHibernate will save it and return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance does not become associated with the session. In most applications with detached objects, you need both methods, `SaveOrUpdate()` and `SaveOrUpdateCopy()`.

What this means is that `existingDocument` is left alone and NHibernate uses entirely different instances to actually perform its actions on.

So what can we do. There are a few options:

1. The result from `SaveOrUpdateCopy` should be the correct `Document`. You can change your code to:

   ```
   existingDocument = (Document)session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(existingDocument);
   ```
2. You can switch to `SaveOrUpdate`. Now, I guess there is a very specific reason this may not be possible for you, because you specifically chose `SaveOrUpdateCopy`. Anyway, `SaveOrUpdate` is what you'd normally use;
3. You can reload the `Document`. This means that after the `SaveOrUpdateCopy`, you could put:

   ```
   var existingDocument = FetchDocumentFromDatabase(someDocumentGuidId);
   ```
4. If you are using `SaveOrUpdateCopy` because `existingDocument` came from a different `ISession`, you can also choose to reattach the `existingDocument` to the current `ISession` using `Lock()`. After you've 'locked' in the `existingDocument` into the new `ISession`, you can use `SaveOrUpdate` instead of `SaveOrUpdateCopy` and that instance, including the `Comment` will then be used and the `Guid` will be assigned.

Comment: I'm curious which of the options you eventually chose.

Comment: Thought about assigning the bounty?

Comment: Sorry I meant to assign it right away, didn't know that I should click the bounty icon (and accept as answer). Now know, thanks.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I just asked because if you forget, I only get half :).